# MYSQL Select Permutations; Require unique values across row

Tags: mysql, optimization, select, unique, permutation

I want to perform a select resulting in a set of **permutations, not combinations**. In other words I want to preform a query which returns rows with **various quantities and arrangements** of the items in my table. **No ID may be repeated horizontally within the same row**.

For example we could have:

```
9 pick 3 
9 pick 5 
9 pick 7
```

I have a working query, but I'm looking to optimize it. The `WHERE...AND...` clause filters out rows with duplicate IDs. While this works, it requires several additional `AND` clauses for each pick (column) added. **For `9 pick 6` Fifteen `!=` assertions are required!** This can become unwieldy as the number of items picked increases. It also looks very bloated. I'm looking for something simple and elegant.

Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col1` varchar(24) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=30 ;

INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `col1`) VALUES
(1, 'Wool Hat'),
(2, 'Wool Gloves'),
(3, 'Fleece Sweater'),
(4, 'Jean Pants'),
(5, 'Cotton T-Shirt'),
(6, 'Wool Socks'),
(7, 'Wool Blanket'),
(8, 'Cotton Boxers'),
(9, 'Fleece Pants');
```

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
`table1` t1, 
`table1` t2, 
`table1` t3,
`table1` t4,
`table1` t5,
`table1` t6

WHERE
t1.id != t2.id
AND
t1.id != t3.id
AND
t1.id != t4.id
AND
t1.id != t5.id
AND
t1.id != t6.id
AND
t2.id != t3.id
AND
t2.id != t4.id
AND
t2.id != t5.id
AND
t2.id != t6.id
AND
t3.id != t4.id 
AND
t3.id != t5.id 
AND
t3.id != t6.id 
AND
t4.id != t5.id
AND
t4.id != t6.id
AND
t5.id != t6.id

ORDER BY t1.col1, t2.col1, t3.col1, t4.col1, t5.col1, t6.col1
```

Thanks for any insight!

EDIT:

The example is really irreverent. I'm just trying to accomplish the mathematical concept of Permutations in a simple and efficient way.

By request, here's half of the expected results for `9 pick 2`. The other half is with the pairs switched.

```
Wool Hat + Wool Gloves
Wool Hat + Fleece Sweater
Wool Hat + Jean Pants
Wool Hat + Cotton T-Shirt
Wool Hat + Wool Socks
Wool Hat + Wool Blanket
Wool Hat + Cotton Boxers
Wool Hat + Fleece Pants
Wool Gloves + Fleece Sweater
Wool Gloves + Jean Pants
Wool Gloves + Cotton T-Shirt
Wool Gloves + Wool Socks
Wool Gloves + Wool Blanket
Wool Gloves + Cotton Boxers
Wool Gloves + Fleece Pants
Fleece Sweater + Jean Pants
Fleece Sweater + Cotton T-Shirt
Fleece Sweater + Wool Socks
Fleece Sweater + Wool Blanket
Fleece Sweater + Cotton Boxers
Fleece Sweater + Fleece Pants
Jean Pants + Cotton T-Shirt
Jean Pants + Wool Socks
Jean Pants + Wool Blanket
Jean Pants + Cotton Boxers
Jean Pants + Fleece Pants
Cotton T-Shirt + Wool Socks
Cotton T-Shirt + Wool Blanket
Cotton T-Shirt + Cotton Boxers
Cotton T-Shirt + Fleece Pants
Wool Socks + Wool Blanket
Wool Socks + Cotton Boxers
Wool Socks + Fleece Pants
Wool Blanket + Cotton Boxers
Wool Blanket + Fleece Pants
```

This excludes the following:

```
Wool Hat + Wool Hat
Wool Gloves + Wool Gloves
Fleece Sweater + Fleece Sweater
Jean Pants + Jean Pants
Cotton T-Shirt + Cotton T-Shirt
Wool Socks + Wool Socks
Wool Blanket + Wool Blanket
Cotton Boxers + Cotton Boxers
Fleece Pants + Fleece Pants
```

Comment: Its hard to understand what you're trying to do with the example provided. Can you post an example using the same values as in your table1?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT
    t1.`id` AS 'id1',
    t2.`id` AS 'id2',
    t1.`col1` AS 't1_col',
    t2.`col1` AS 't2_col',
    CONCAT(t1.`col1`,' + ',t2.`col1`) AS 'combined'
FROM `table1` t1
CROSS JOIN `table1` t2
WHERE t1.`id` != t2.`id`
-- or
-- WHERE t1.`id` < t2.`id`
ORDER BY t1.`id`,t2.`id`
```

**[EDIT]** Another option is to use JOINS. Here's an example for your `9 pick 3`.

```
SELECT
    t1.`id` AS 'id1',
    t2.`id` AS 'id2',
    t3.`id` AS 'id3',
    t1.`col1` AS 't1_col',
    t2.`col1` AS 't2_col',
    t3.`col1` AS 't3_col',
    CONCAT_WS(' + ',t1.`col1`,t2.`col1`,t3.`col1`) AS 'combined'
FROM `table1` t1
INNER JOIN `table1` t2
INNER JOIN `table1` t3
ON
    t2.`id` > t1.`id` AND
    t3.`id` > t2.`id`
ORDER BY t1.`id`,t2.`id`,t3.`id`
```

Comment: sure, this works for `9 pick 2`. however when you expand this to say `9 pick 6` it gets cluttered. Your using the same `WHERE id1 != id2` syntax that *I stated I don't want to use*.

Comment: @skibulk I added a JOIN version. I don't see how you can do that without using such a condition since you're joining the same table multiple times.

Comment: Remember permutations, not combinations, so I need every possible order as well. That means using `!=` instead of `>`. You missed `t1 != t3`. For `9 pick 6` this solution requires *Fifteen* `id != id` assertions! I just wish there was something more streamlined.

Comment: @skibulk It seems I confused the terms (see, it's been 15 yrs since the time I studied those :) And you're right about the missing condition if it's gonna be a permutation.